# how to get partial response from $.ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax

let's say I want to use
$.ajax

to get the result from a php page ie.

```
$.get("mypage.php", { 'id': "175" }, function(result) {
              console.log(result);
});
```

in here, result will be:

```
<html>
<body>
...
<div id="container">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when using .load() I can specify which element I'm interested in. ie. `$('.mydiv').load("something.html #container")` which I will only get the container. I wonder if $.ajax can do something similar, so that I can do something like this:

```
$.get("mypage.php", { 'id': "175" }, function(result) {
                  console.log(result #container); //only gives me the <div id="container"> element
    });
```

Comment: `$.get("mypage.php", { 'id': "175" }, function(result) { console.log($(result).find('#container');});`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think you are allowed to post answers as answers.

Comment: @GolezTrol Posting answers from mobile is a lot of work and generally I prefer not to answer such jQuery basic questions. However a lot of times people come to SO because they need a quick fix to their problem and if I'm able to provide that quick fix there is no reason not to :) Getting the answer _fast_ is part of what's awesome about SO and I'm sure someone will provide a better in depth answer soon.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum it works fine, thanks (will give you a vote if you post your answer here) :)

Comment: @Josh Very well, since you did not get a satisfactory answer so far and a day has passed I've decided to answer it :) Let me know if there is anything I should clarify in the answer - I'll gladly do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite possible and not very complicated. When you make an AJAX request (like you do with jQuery) to an HTML page you get its content.

You can then turn that content into a DOM and run jQuery selectors on it. Basically what happens is that you create an empty root element, run the selector against it and extract that. This is basically what `.load` does.

```
$.get("mypage.php", { 'id': "175" }, function(result) { 
     console.log($(result).find('#container');
});
```

This reads as : Get mypage.php?id=175 , when you're done - build an actual page from that HTML string and select #container from it.

This is, exactly what `.load` does. From the jQuery source code:

```
 jQuery("<div>").append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText)).find(selector)
```

As you can see, it gets the response text (result in *your* case) puts it in a dummy `<div>` and finds `selector` in it (similarly to `#container` in our case).

Answer (score 2):

I believe jQuery will create a document fragment for you:

```
var fragment = $(result);
```

Then, you can query the fragment for the element that you're interested in:

```
var container = $('#container', fragment);
```

And finally, if you want to see the html:

```
container.html()
```